# Could useful quantities of materials be extracted from sewage?

Tags: cities

"Useful quantities" is relative to whatever's being extracted. You also can't destroy the water the materials are being extracted from. It has to be economical compared to the conventional methods of getting whatever's being extracted. The technology level is near future. There is sewerage from an area 18.5 million people available. What is being extracted is up to you, it just has to be economically viable against getting the materiel normally. Could useful quantities of something be extracted from sewage?

Comment: By 'materials', are we including energy? Because there's a lot of work going into getting energy from sewage. If you mean minerals, I've read less about that.

Comment: @Humphrey it can be anything other than energy

Comment: There are valuable items that always can be found in sewage (though they are not sewage themselves).

Answer (score 4):

The extraction of [methane](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2010/oct/05/human-waste-turned-renewable-gas) and [heat energy](https://www.cibsejournal.com/general/londons-hidden-energy-source-recovering-heat-from-sewage/) from sewage are both already a commercial reality at a number of treatment plants in different parts of the world. Dried solid waste can be used as feed stock for [biodigesters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_digestion) to create more methane or composted for fertiliser.

Salt, [Saltpeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_nitrate), and [urea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urea) are compounds that can easily be [leached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaching_(chemistry)) from raw waste, but not at rates and costs that compete with modern mining or chemical production methods. In the case of Saltpeter and Urea in particular waste extraction was once the source of almost all of the available supply.

Comment: One addition: phosphorus, [it is already happening](https://iwa-network.org/phosphorus-recovery-and-reuse-from-wastewater/) and EU estimates that [around 50% of P in sewage](https://europa.eu/regions-and-cities/programme/sessions/1315_en) is reused as fertilizer

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza Cool, I didn't know about that, that's worth an answer of it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I put it in a comment, but I'll make an answer out of it

With current technology, phosphorus can be leached effectively from sewage, [it is already happening](https://iwa-network.org/phosphorus-recovery-and-reuse-from-wastewater/). The EU estimates that around [50% of phosphorus in sewage](https://europa.eu/regions-and-cities/programme/sessions/1315_en) is currently recovered and reused as fertilizer.

It is also possible to [recover nitrogen](http://www.circulary.eu/project/yara-recovery/) from wastewater, also to be reused as fertilizer, with some more modern techniques that can get pretty competitive depending on the infrastructure

Another process that goes on today is the [extraction of methane](https://www.wri.org/insights/wastewater-best-hidden-energy-source-youve-never-heard) from wastewater sludge, effectively making the WWTP self-sufficient

That's not considering industrial waste - that's even better to recover stuff from as it is far more predictable than sanitary waste